# How to setup a local dev environment for non-Shopify Liquid projects?

Tags: frontend, e-commerce, liquid, web-frontend, liquid-template

### The Issue

I'm trying to create a theme for a client on a Shopify-like platform called [EasyStore](https://developers.easystore.co/docs/theme/getting-started). After having looked through their documentation and developer area, they don't seem to have robust support for theme building yet. They have no staging area which means I would have to develop a theme while the website is live. This brings me to my question, how can I set up a non-Shopify Liquid local dev environment?

### What I've tried

- I've tried using Live Server in VSCode but unfortunately there's no support for Liquid.
- Thought I could use shopify-cli but I would need to upload that theme to Shopify.
- Locally develop the front-end portion of the website(HTML/CSS/JS), then upload it and add in Liquid to test the functionality of the website. Since there is no staging area I will be doing this while the website is live which isn't a big issue as the brand hasn't been launched yet.

Is there a better solution? Thanks for reading!